# Is there a way to better fit a PCI-E x8 card into an x16 slot?

Tags: pci-express

I have a PCI Express card with an x8 connector, plugged into an x16 slot. The problem is that because the connector is much shorter than the slot, it doesn't seem to be a tight enough fit, and I'm worried that it might not get a good connection.

Since I don't have any other slots to plug it in (only x16 and x1 on this board), I wonder if there's something like a blind that I can insert into the slot to fill it and make sure that the back of the connector is pushing against this blind rather than just air?

Comment: I have never seen anything like a spacer or plug to fill the extra  space... And have never had a 8x card in a 16x slot have a poor connection. Once the card is inserted and fastened/screwed down, it certainly shouldn't move.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen anything to 'fill' the remaining space, and I would advise you to avoid this so that you don't damage the pins. There are other design features that should ensure a good and accurate fit.

Remember, a "*tight*" fit does not necessarily mean a "*good*" fit. In this case the pins are spring loaded to provide a good contact with the card-edge connector, and it doesn't typically feel "*tight*" - especially with the lower pin-count cards.

The key in the connector should ensure correct horizontal alignment, such that the pins and pads aren't misaligned:

[image: PCIe x16 with key marked]

Additionally, the card's bracket should provide a fixing hole so that the bracket can be attached securely to the chassis / enclosure - to ensure that the card doesn't come out of the socket:

[image: PCI bracket fixing hole]

The bottom of this bracket should fit into a slot in the chassis to further ensure correct alignment.

This side-view graphic, courtesy of [Samtec](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/pcie.pdf) shows the spring-loaded pins (I've colored the pins):

[image: spring loaded pins]

These connectors are designed specifically to mate with a 1.6mm PCB - so if the connection feels overly loose or you're having functional issues, then you could always check the PCB thickness... though a PCB of anything other than 1.6mm is out-of-spec - something that may be true for an especially cheap card.